# Sum three tables

Tags: sql, sum

I want to get 2 sums from 3 tables:

```
tbl_header
id   id_quotation   description
1    1              descr_1
2    2              descr_2

tbl_body
id   id_quotation   id_item  item_cost
1    1              1        400
2    1              2        300

tbl_money
id   id_quotation   amount
1    1              200
2    1              300
3    2              100
```

So I need 1 query to get the description from the tbl_head `SUM(tbl_body.item_cost) WHERE tbl_body.id_quotation = 1` (in this case 400+300=700) and `SUM(tbl_money.amount) WHERE id_quotation=1` (in this case 200+300=500). `Id_quotation` is the same field in all tables.

I did it with this query:

```
select    head.description,
          sum(body.item_cost) as sum_1,
          (select   sum(money.amount)
           from     tbl_money money
           where    money.idquotation=head.idquotation
           GROUP BY money.id_quotation) as sum_2
FROM      tbl_body as body,
          tbl_header as head
WHERE     head.id_quotation=body.id_quotation
GROUP BY  head.description
```

Now I'd like to eliminate the inner query `select sum(money.amount) from ...` and replace it with something like `SUM(money.amount)` but I always get the record 3 times so the sum is three times bigger. The query that doesn't work is:

```
SELECT        head.description,
              Sum(body.item_cost) AS sum_1,
              sum(money.amount) as sum_2
FROM          (tbl_header head
               INNER JOIN tbl_body body
               ON head.id_quotation=body.id_quotation)
  INNER JOIN  tbl_money money
  ON          head.id_quotation=money.id_quotation
WHERE         head.id_person=1
  AND         money.id_quotation=body.id_quotation
GROUP BY      head.description;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
select min(header.description), SUM(body3.item_cost), SUM(money.amount)
from tbl_header header
    left outer join tbl_body body on header.id_quotation = body.id_quotation
    left outer join tbl_body body1 on body1.id< body.id
    left outer join tbl_body body2 on body2.id> body.id
    left outer join tbl_money money on money.id_quotation = header.id_quotation and body1.id is null
    left outer join tbl_body body3 on body3.id_quotation=header.id_quotation and body2.id is null
where header.id_quotation = 1 
group by header.id_quotation
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fine, although I would put the subquery in the `from` clause and fix the join to use proper join syntax.  There is a trick to do what you want.  Although I don't recommend it, I will show you:

```
select    head.description,
          sum(body.item_cost)/count(distinct money.id) as sum_1,
          sum(money) / count(distinct money.id) as sum_2
FROM      tbl_body body join
          tbl_header head
          on head.id_quotation=body.id_quotation join
          tbl_money
          on money.idquotation = head.idquotation
GROUP BY  head.description
```

That is, divide out the counts of the duplicates.  I would only ever do this for the quickest and dirtiest queries.

The recommended way is to do the summary on the money table before the join:

```
select    head.description,
          sum(body.item_cost) as sum_1,
          sum(money) as sum_2
FROM      tbl_body body join
          tbl_header head
          on head.id_quotation=body.id_quotation join
          (select idquotation, SUM(money) as money
           from tbl_money
           group by idquotation
          ) money
          on money.idquotation = head.idquotation
GROUP BY  head.description
```